# In the MC architecture, mutual references cause memory leaks. How do I change a good design program?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Click the button, QTabWidget will add a tab (patient object).

Here's how I designed it.

First, the model requests the network to call the patient method after the data is obtained to display the data.

Second, the patient will actively use the data in the model.

So I defined self.model = Model () and self.view = view, but this created a problem. Patient and model refer to each other, which will cause a memory leak. So when I closed the tab, I had to delete patient.model. Attributes so that they are no longer referenced by each other, and the problem of memory leaks has been resolved.

However, in my project, I have many cases where the view and model reference each other. I need to find them all, and then close the relationship between them when closing the tab. I think this design is a bit weak on memory leaks. Can you give me some better design suggestions? Thank you very much.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QTabWidget, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton


class Model(object):
    def __init__(self, view):
        self.view = view


class Patient(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Patient, self).__init__()
        self.model = Model(self)
        self.data = [map(lambda x: {'name': 'ken'}, [x for x in range(10000000)])]


class Tab(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Tab, self).__init__()
        self.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.delete)

    def add(self):
        self.addTab(Patient(), 'name')

    def delete(self, index):
        patient = self.widget(index)
        self.removeTab(index)

        import sip
        sip.delete(patient)
        del patient.model


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)

        self.tab = Tab()
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.tab)

        btn = QPushButton()
        btn.clicked.connect(self.click)
        self.hbox.addWidget(btn)

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt")
        self.show()

    def click(self):
        self.tab.add()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always use Model and Patient classes, you could use the [`destroyed()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed) signal to be notified when a widget is removed, and delete the model.

Since `deleteLater()` also takes care of disconnecting all slots related to the destroying object, the method cannot be called on its own instance. To circumvent this, using a lambda can solve the issue.

```
class Patient(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Patient, self).__init__()
        self.model = Model(self)
        self.data = [map(lambda x: {'name': 'ken'}, [x for x in range(10000000)])]
        self.destroyed.connect(lambda: self.aboutToBeDeleted())

    def aboutToBeDeleted(self):
        del self.model


class Tab(QTabWidget):
    #...
    def delete(self, index):
        patient = self.widget(index)
        self.removeTab(index)
        patient.deleteLater()
```

This should take care of everything, including disconnecting all slots and signals related to `patient`. Calling [`deleteLater()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) should also be enough, instead of using sip.delete (which I believe is done anyway by deleteLater).

Comment: I modified my code according to your suggestions. I printed some information in the aboutToBeDeleted method to see if the method was actually called. When I closed the tab, I found that it did not print the information on the console, indicating that it was not called.

In addition, how to delete the widget, I use the method recorded in my previous note:

Widget does not depend on other child widgets to use deleteLater

Widgets depend on other child widgets to use sip.delete

I don't know if my notes are wrong.

Comment: @redj I forgot that at the point when destroyed is emitted, the signals related to the object are already disconnected. You can workaround this by calling the method using a lambda. See my edit.

Comment: I used your code, it really works, I even modified it, I wrote it as a separate class, this class inherits from QWidget, the code is below (I answered my own question), I am in the project I use the Widget class that I rewrite, so that each widget will call the _destroyed method when it is deleted, and set the properties in this class to None, which solves the problem of mutual reference, which I think has already been It solves my problem very well, but I don't know if there will be new hidden dangers. What is your suggestion? Thank you

Comment: It ’s unfortunate to report an error in this line：self.destroyed.connect(lambda: self._destroyed())The error message is：NameError: free variable 'self' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Comment: line 10, in <lambda>
    self.destroyed.connect(lambda: self._destroyed())
NameError: free variable 'self' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Comment: I'm beginning to believe that you're trying to be a bit *too thorough* about this, seeing your last comment and the other answer (by the way, you shouldn't add new answers if they don't actually add something very new to existing answers, especially if that new answer is conceptually the same one: it's considered noise and bad practice). Using deleteLater should be enough to free the underlying object, Python's garbage collector will take care of the rest if you don't have other references.

Comment: Hello, I solved the problem of reporting errors, I changed the signal to this way：QObject.connect(self, SIGNAL("destroyed"), lambda: self._destroyed())

Comment: @redj good. Anyway, if your structure is as depicted in your previous "answer", you really don't need to go through all this, just be careful about not keeping references in existing objects when deleting a widget: if there's not, both sip and python's garbage collector will safely take care of it.